# Find the Derivative:

Tags: calculus, derivatives, hyperbolic-functions

This problem for my Calculus 1 class has got me stumped. I am not sure on where to start for this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

$y=x\tanh^{-1}(x) + \ln(\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Comment: Product and chain rule allow you to deal with all the terms up to the derivative of $\tanh^{-1}$. For that one you recall that $f\circ f^{-1}(x)=x$ and use the chain rule to get an expression for $(f^{-1})'$ (ultimately you obtain the first expression in this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation )

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

$$\text{arctanh}(x)=\frac12\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$

Then, use the product rule along with the chain rule.

Can you proceed now?

Comment: Yes I think so. I will comment if I still don't get it. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

$${ y }^{ \prime  }={ \left( x\tanh ^{ -1 } (x)+\ln { \left( \sqrt { 1-x^{ 2 } }  \right)  }  \right)  }^{ \prime  }={ \left( x\tanh ^{ -1 } (x) \right)  }^{ \prime  }+{ \left( \ln { \left( \sqrt { 1-x^{ 2 } }  \right)  }  \right)  }^{ \prime  }=\\ ={ x }^{ \prime  }\tanh ^{ -1 } (x)+x{ \left( \tanh ^{ -1 } (x) \right)  }^{ \prime  }+\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 1-x^{ 2 } }  } { \left( \sqrt { 1-x^{ 2 } }  \right)  }^{ \prime  }=\\ =\tanh ^{ -1 } (x)+\frac { x }{ 1-{ x }^{ 2 } } -\frac { 2x }{ 1-{ x }^{ 2 } } =\tanh ^{ -1 } (x)-\frac { x }{ 1-{ x }^{ 2 } } $$

Answer (score 0):

$y=x\tanh^{−1}(x)+\ln(\sqrt{1−x^2})$

differentiation is linear
$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac d{dx} (x\tanh^{−1}(x)) +\frac d{dx}(\ln(\sqrt{1−x^2})$

next we need to know the product rule and the chain rule

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \tanh^{−1}(x) + x\frac d{dx} \tanh^{−1}(x) +\frac {1}{\sqrt{1−x^2}} \frac d{dx}\sqrt{1−x^2}\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \tanh^{−1}(x) + x\frac d{dx} \tanh^{−1}(x) +\frac {1}{\sqrt{1−x^2}} \frac {-x}{\sqrt{1−x^2}}\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \tanh^{−1}(x) + x\frac d{dx} \tanh^{−1}(x) -\frac {x}{1−x^2}$

Which leave one nasty left to tackle

$u = \tanh^{-1} x\\
\tanh u = x\\
\sech^2 u \frac {du}{dx} = 1\\
\frac {du}{dx} = \frac 1{\sech^2 u}\\
\frac {du}{dx} = \frac 1{1-\tanh^2 u}\\
\frac {du}{dx} = \frac 1{1- x^2}\\
$

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \tanh^{−1}(x) + \frac {x}{1-x^2} -\frac {x}{1−x^2}\\
\frac {dy}{dx} = \tanh^{−1}(x)$

Answer (score 0):

First note that for $f(x)=\tanh(x)$ , using the quotient rule from the definition of $\tanh x =\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}$, we can write the derivative as:
$$
f'(x)=1-\tanh^2 x
$$
Now using the derivative of the inverse function:
$$
\frac {d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}
$$
we have:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\tanh^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}
$$

so your derivative, using product and chain rules, becomes:
$$
y'=\tanh^{-1}(x)+\frac{x}{1-x^2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\left(\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} \right)=\tanh^{-1}(x)+\frac{x}{1-x^2}-\frac{x}{1-x^2}=\tanh^{-1}(x)
$$